# With xml.etree, How to I create namespaced attribute "XML:lang"?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I am trying to make a simple xml converter for TMX format using xml.etree. How do I create the language attribute that looks like this: `xml:lang`.

What I tried:

```
    root = et.Element("tmx")
    body = et.SubElement(root, "body")
    tu = et.SubElement(body, "tu")
    tuv_en = et.SubElement(tu, "tuv", xml:lang="en")  # 'xml:lang' gets error
    tuv_zh = et.SubElement(tu, "tuv", xml:lang="zh")
    seg_en = et.SubElement(tuv_en, "segment").text="en text."
    seg_zh = et.SubElement(tuv_zh, "segment").text="zh text."
    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write( file + ".xml")
```

What I want:

```
<tmx>
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>en text.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="zh">
        <seg>zh text.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

Comment: Have you tried `et.register_namespace` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `attrib` keyword argument:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

root = et.Element("tmx")
body = et.SubElement(root, "body")

tu = et.SubElement(body, "tu")
et.SubElement(tu, "tuv", attrib={"xml:lang": "en"})
et.SubElement(tu, "tuv", attrib={"xml:lang": "zh"})

print(et.tostring(body))
```

This would produce:

```
<body><tu><tuv xml:lang="en" /><tuv xml:lang="zh" /></tu></body>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have an existing lxml etree dom and can't use ElementTree, you can set the attribute like this:

```
from lxml import etree

element = etree.Element("element")

# This won't work: element.set("xml:lang", "en")
element.set("{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang", "en")

print(etree.tostring(element))
```

Result:

```
<element xml:lang="en"/>
```